# Is there a Hive SerDe for CSV file to infer schema from file header

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a CSV file, with first line as a header. Is there a HIVE SerDe that can create table using CSV header as well infers data type then it is the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer - No.

What you're looking for is outside the scope of what SerDes are designed to do.  There are, however, tools available that will create a table from a CSV with headers as an intermediate step.  Check out hue.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I came across Hue but it is a UI portal and what I need is a constant running query to work with CSV file header.
My problem is that I am collecting stream data with a following schema, but here user can change schema in an ongoing process. Thereby, after that moment what I will receive is data with new schema. Here schema change is add, remove or rename a column.
So I need some solution that can understand schema and create Hive table appropriately as I need to encapsulate different schemas in one Hive table.